# When binding data to kendo-grid got error Type 'T[] | null' is not assignable to type 'any[]' in Angular app

Tags: angular, rxjs, kendo-grid

I'm getting data from http request (from json file) in service (products.service.ts):

```
  products$ = this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl)
    .pipe(
      map(products =>
        products.map(product => ({
          ...product,
          //price: product.price ? product.price * 1.5 : 0,
          searchKey: [product.ProductName]
        } as IProduct))),
      tap(data => console.log('Products: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

Then in component (app.component.ts):

products$ = this.productsService.products$
.pipe(
catchError(err => {
this.errorMessage = err;
return EMPTY;
})
);

Then in the HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{products: products$|async} as data">
  <kendo-grid
    [kendoGridBinding]="data.products"
    [height]="400"
    [pageable]="true"
    [pageSize]="10"
  >
```

Text of an error:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:4:6 - error TS2322: Type 'IProduct[] | null' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

4     [kendoGridBinding]="data.products"
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:11:16
    11   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

I put this small application here [github.com/sam-klok/angular-kendo-grid-reactive](https://github.com/sam-klok/angular-kendo-grid-reactive)
Screens:

[image: screen shot HTML]

[image: screen shot with error]

[image]

Comment: `async` pipes return `null` if there is no data in the `Observable`, which means `.products` may be `null`.

Comment: Correct, could be no data, but how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async pipe have opportunity to filter errors, it must include `null` (or `undefined`) in its type because the stream may not have emitted a value by the time the template executes.

Here is the interface of returning value of async pipe

```
transform<T>(obj: Observable<T> | Subscribable<T> | Promise<T>): T | null;
```

As you can see it adds `null` to actual result, but your property `[kendoGridBinding]` accepting only `any[]`, and because of your actual result equals to `IProduct[] | null` it says that `*Type` `null` is not assignable to type `any[]`

So you can just add `null` check for your property.

For example:

```html
<kendo-grid
    [kendoGridBinding]="data.products || []"
    [height]="400"
    [pageable]="true"
    [pageSize]="10"
>
```

Comment: This fix works. Is it possible to do conversion of the time for products$ in the component/service?

Comment: Actually in component you can subscribe to `products$` and define another public property `products` (which will be sync property of your class), and in callback of subscription you can assign it to `this.property` and use it in template, and don't forget to assign default value as empty array to avoid null check. But anyway using observable with async pipe is better solution than this example.